# Dual Base URL in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have installed the XAMPP and Moodle 2.5 inside it.

Along side, I've also installed No-ip client to convert this to a webserver.

Now my question is, I woud like to have this server reacheble from my intranet and from outside.

My `config.php` file have base url like:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://172.16.1.1/exam';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'H:\\xampp\\moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';
```

But not limited to local ip address, I want to use it as webserver to access it from internet. Please suggest me how to set the base url to use it from internet and also from my intranet.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is use a domain name which can be accessed from both internet and internal machines.

Failing that, the Moodle config file is simply a PHP file so you can do something like this:

```
if (access_via_internet()) {
    $CFG->wwwroot = WEBROOT_FOR_INTERNET_ACCESS;
} else if (access_via_intranet()) {
    $CFG->wwwroot = WEBROOT_FOR_INTRANET_ACCESS;
} else {
    throw new Exception("Ye cannae change the laws of physics");
}

function access_via_internet() {
    // Do something to detect access via the internet.
    // Probably parse $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    return (did_we_detect_the_internet() ? true : false);
}

function access_via_intranet() {
    // Do something to detect access via the intranet.
    // Probably just negate the value of access_via_internet()
    return !access_via_internet();
}
```

Another option is to just rely on the server address by which the user came to you:

```
$CFG->wwwroot = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/exam';
```

One potential issue, if you do allow access from different addresses: do not copy and paste Moodle URLs into course content. It's easy to forget, but the URLS will only work for users also accessing from the same route.

Comment: I use `SERVER_NAME` for this purpose. Locally, I've set my server to have a specific name.

Comment: It is important to note, that this approach will not only break when posting LMS links inside things, but some features of Moodle, and certainly many add-ons will rely on the wwwroot/httpswwwroot for proper operation, and could fail as a result of the value being variable in the config.  It may be better to use an apache mod to make both entry points look like the same entry point before php gets its hands on the requests.